# Can the clustering keys be defined on temporary and transient tables?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I understand that the clustering can be defined on a permanent table. But, Can the same be defined on temporary and transient table?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to test it?

```
create or replace temporary table x_temp (id number, v varchar ) cluster by (id) as select UNIFORM(0,100,random()), 'xyz'  from table(generator(rowcount=>10000000));
create or replace transient table x_transient (id number, v varchar ) cluster by (id) as select UNIFORM(0,100,random()), 'xyz'  from table(generator(rowcount=>10000000));

select system$clustering_information( 'x_temp');
select system$clustering_information( 'x_transient');
```

You may define clustering keys for transient and temp tables. Although it's possible to define a clustering key for a temporary table, I do not think it will provide any benefits, as the clustering service will not be able to re-cluster it.

New sample based on the comment:

```
create or replace transient table x_transient_v2 (id number, v varchar ) cluster by (id) 
as select UNIFORM(0,10,random()), RANDSTR( 1000, random())  from table(generator(rowcount=>500000));

select system$clustering_information( 'x_transient_v2'); -- save the output to compare

insert into x_transient_v2 select UNIFORM(0,10,random()), RANDSTR( 1000, random())  from table(generator(rowcount=>50000));
update x_transient_v2 set v = RANDSTR( 1000, random()) where v ilike 'A%';
insert into x_transient_v2 select UNIFORM(0,10,random()), RANDSTR( 1000, random())  from table(generator(rowcount=>50000)); 

select system$clustering_information( 'x_transient_v2'); -- compare the output with the first one

select *
from table(information_schema.automatic_clustering_history(
date_range_start=>dateadd(d, -1, current_date),
date_range_end=>current_date,
table_name=>'X_TRANSIENT_V2')); -- wait for a while until you see a row which has NUM_ROWS_RECLUSTERED is not zero

select system$clustering_information( 'x_transient_v2'); -- compare the output which should be similar to first
```

Comment: Yes, I did check it Gokhan. Usually, A well-clustered table should have a constant depth (which is 1). But, In this example, It's 8. So, I don't think it's functioning as expected in the background

Comment: For the temp table, as I said, I don't think clustering will work. But for the transient table, it should work but auto-clustering is a background service, and it does not cluster the table immediately. I modified the sample to show it works on the transient table.

Comment: Thank you so much, Gokhan! I'll go through them

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes you can ALTER CLUSTER BY a transient or temporary table.

But i'm not sure that the induced cost and expected performance will suit your use case.
You should read the [Snowflake documention on clustered tables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html) because clustering keys are not intended for all tables. You have to consider table size and performance.

Comment: Sure CMe. I'll check it once